# Rails3 form partial reuse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The following is the Rails std form that works.

```
<div id="content-form">
  <%= form_for @passion, url: passion_path do |f| %>
    <%#= render :partial => "form", :f => f %>
    <div class="alternate">
      <%= f.label "Status" %>
      <%= f.text_field :status %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Now I extract the partial to `_form.html.erb` with the following:

```
<div class="alternate">
  <%= f.label "Status" %>
  <%= f.text_field :status %>
</div>
```

And update the form as:

```
<div id="content-form">
  <%= form_for @passion, url: passion_path do |f| %>
    <%= render :partial => "form", :f => f %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But now this throws an error complaining about the `f` variable.

```
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x0000012d51d3e8>:0x0000012d796ef8>

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <div class="alternate">
2:   <%= f.label "Status" %>
3:   <%= f.text_field :status %>
4: </div>
```

Why is this? Its pretty Rails basic.

One thing to consider that the resource `@passion` is singular. i.e. `resource :passion` (user has_one passion)

Due to that, I've to use explicit `url: passion_path` in the `form_for ...`.

Btw, using Rails 3.2.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try this

<div id="content-form">
<%= form_for @passion, url: passion_path do |f| %>
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals=>{:f => f } %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `:partial` option, which means you have to pass local variables in with `:locals`:

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f } %>
```

The less verbose option is:

```
<%= render "form", :f => f %>
```